# JSF - Load/insert a different div after an ajax call

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I think the topic explain what Im looking for :

`template.xhtml`

```
<div class="content">
    <ui:insert name="content_homepage">Box Content Here</ui:insert>
</div>
```

`index.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition template="./template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">
        JSF - The Sinfonet Portal
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="login">
        <h:form id="form1" prependId="false">
            <h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" target="head" />

            <span class="menu_span">Username</span>
            <h:inputText value="#{login.name}" id="name" />

            <span class="menu_span">
                <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{login.checkLogin}">
                        <f:ajax event="action" execute="name" render="??????"/>
                </h:commandButton>                    
            </span>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content_homepage">
        <span class="content_title">Homepage</span>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content_logged">
        <span class="content_title">OK. You are logged</span>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Managed bean

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="login")
@RequestScoped
public class Login {
    private String name = "";

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String newValue) { name = newValue; }

    public boolean checkLogin() {
        if(name.length()==0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }   
}
```

By using template definition, I insert the `content_homepage` as first content. After, when i do an ajax call, if the name isnt empty, I will load `content_login`. Is it possible to do this on JSF?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to separate the concepts of Facelets (the view/templating technology) and JSF (the component based MVC framework). What you want is not possible with alone Facelets since the Facelets `ui` tags are solely server side and doesn't emit anything to client side. You need to bring in a JSF component (which generates at end HTML) which can be located by the JS/Ajax in the client side.

`template.xhtml`

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="content">
    <ui:insert name="content_homepage">Box Content Here</ui:insert>
</h:panelGroup>
```

*(the `layout="block"` makes it a `<div>` instead of `<span>`)*

The button of `index.html`:

```
            <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{login.checkLogin}">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":content" />
            </h:commandButton>
```

*(the `:content` refers to `<h:panelGroup id="content">` which is located in upper `:` level)*

The content template definition of `index.html`:

```
<ui:define name="content_homepage">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!login.loggedIn}">
        User is not logged in.
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{login.loggedIn}">
        User is logged in.
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:define>
```

Managed bean:

```
private String name; // Do NOT initialize with empty string! Poor practice.

// ...

public boolean isLoggedIn() { // Boolean getter methods should be prefixed with `is`.
    return name != null; // Do NOT add if/else verbosity for something which already returns boolean! Poor practice.
}
```

Further, don't use spans as labels. That's bad HTML semantics. Use `<h:outputLabel>` (or plain HTML `<label>`).

Comment: I don't know how to say : this is not a explanation...this is the EXPLANATION! Many thanks man, you really learn to me many things about JSF with this explanation. Its also nice to see that i didnt to add any kind of control to the Tomcat session, because i can manage the status with Beans (SessionScoped). Very nice! I know, i need to get familiar with this framework, his behavior looks a bit strange at the moment, but i'm learning! Thanks to you, AGAIN!!! :)